# Token renewal operation failed due to timeout in MSAL Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal

Hello i'm building an angular application with SSO login using azure/msal-angular npm package

everything works perfect but sometimes it shows this error in console "Token renewal operation failed due to timeout" as you show in below image link.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq5pS.png)

**Here is my auth guard Code**

```
async canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    var allowedRoles = next.data;
   
    // check if logged in MSAL
    this.isLoggedIn = await !!this.msalService.getAccount();
    if (this.isLoggedIn) {
      this.user = await this.msalService.getAccount();
      localStorage.setItem('userName', this.user.name);
      var isAdmin = false;
      var userDataObj = this.authService.getUserDataFromSession()
      if (userDataObj) {
        this.userData = userDataObj;
      }
      else {
        this.userData = await this.authService.getUserRoleByEmail(this.user.userName);
      }
    

      if (this.userData) {
        for (const key in allowedRoles) {
          const element = allowedRoles[key];
          console.log(state.url);
          console.log(element.toLowerCase(), this.userData.type);
          if (state.url == '/' && this.userData.type == 'hq') {
            this.router.navigate(['admin']);
            break;
          }
          else if (state.url == '/' && this.userData.type == 'manager') {
            this.router.navigate(['manager']);
            break;
          }
          else if (element.toLowerCase() == 'manager' && this.userData.type == 'manager') {
            return true;
          }
          else if (element.toLowerCase() == 'admin' && this.userData.type == 'hq') {
            return true;
          } else if (element.toLowerCase() == 'employee' && this.userData.type == 'emp') {
            return true;
          } else {
            console.log("You are not allowed to access this page.-->>", state.url);
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
    
      return false;
    }

  }
```

**MSAL Configuration in-app module file**

```
  MsalModule.forRoot({
      auth: {
        clientId: environment.clientId,
        authority: environment.authority,
        validateAuthority: true,
        redirectUri: environment.redirectUrl,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: environment.redirectUrl,
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true
      },
      cache: {
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
      }
    }),
```

can you please help me to solve this token error, and how to get a new token?

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade to the latest msal (1.4.3) library and also the latest @azure/msal-angular (1.1.1)?

Comment: @pixelbits , after upgrading this token issue will be solved ?...Currently in package.json file I have this versions ...."msal": "^1.4.0","@azure/msal-angular": "^1.1.1",

Comment: ...um try it out?